# Problems when bringing node with angular OR how to create a mean app without using angular-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am using angular4. I used angular-cli to create my project.

I want to use node.js as server side language with mongodb. So, I found a tutorial [here](http://tattoocoder.com/angular2-giving-your-cli-server/) to connect node.js with angular.

But there are two problems with it:

1. dist folder is created.
2. auto refresh server like using nodemon or similar is lost

**problem with dist folder**

My site depends heavily on images. I keep all the images in a folder called images which is located under assets folder created by angular-cli

So, when I run the server, all the assets will be copied to the dist directory, which will take time and (more important) space on the webserver. Another problem is that If I upload new images, then it will be copied to the images folder inside dist folder, so I have to manually copy those images to my original dist folder.

Another copy of images folder in dist folder will take double space than my original app. So, I have to pay more money for hosting to use more space.

**problem with auto-refresh server**

before using node, I just typed this command

```
ng serve
```

and my application started. Then when I change any code and save the file, the changes were reflected in the browser without restarting the server.

But when I started to use node, I have to manually restart the server whenever I make changes to my code.

**Question:**

Is there any way that prevents app to create images folder inside dist folder to save space. I mean can I use original Images folder instead of creating one inside dist?

Or is there any other way that a node application and angular application work together?

#### If anybody knows a solution that does not use dist folder, then I would love to use that solution. As my need is satisfied. Auto-refresh server is not important to me in this case.

#### So, if anybody knows a way of how to create a mean app without angular-cli,
 then I think that is very near to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change dist folder's name  to any name you want. you just need to find file .angular-cli.json in your main root folder and change json

```
"apps": [
    {
      ...,
      "outDir": "dist", // dist to any name e.g. public, ...
      ...
   }
]
```

Comment: I don't want to change the name of dist folder. Instead I want to reference my images directly from the original assets folder instead of referencing images from assets folder inside dist folder.